# Flutter App Crash on android 12 Installing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using flutter sdk 3.0.4

I try to open app in android 12, It's show me blank screen and getting stuck. I added android:exported:true  in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.customer.restow.restowcustomer">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application android:label="restowcustomer" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCG4kNsi-MmkxEJ06MO0QlwGyLL3SiLNfQ" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Comment: Can you share more on android manifest file or share screenshot of it

Comment: you are using a package that generates this problem make sure to update all of your packages to the latest and most compatible one.

Comment: Is there any kind of debug output?

Comment: Can you share the pubspec.yaml file?